# IE toolbar Installatiobn issues

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, toolbar

I am developing the IE toolbar and want to install 2 instance of toolbar at a time and both must be active, so what changes i must do and where?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the GUIDs in each eand every place. Create new GUIDs and try installing the toolbar.